# using facebook graph api to share status update in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying out facebook graph api for functionalities of `like`, `share` etc. I need to share newsfeed of a particular friend. The newsfeed can be any- photo, video, link or status update.
i am able to share everything but status update. following is my code:

```
if ([strType isEqualToString:@"status"]) {


            [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"message"];

            if (text == nil) {
                text = [[resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] objectForKey:@"story"];
            }



            NSDictionary *dict = [resultArrFeed objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
            NSLog(@"dic : %@", dict);
            NSString *str = [[dict valueForKey:@"actions"] valueForKey:@"link"][0];
            dic=[NSDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:str,@"link",nil];
            request=[NSMutableString stringWithString: @"me/feed/"];
            //  [dic setValue:str forKey:@"link"];
            NSLog(@" %@", str);

        }
```

i get the following error on sharing:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xaaa9a20 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 1500;
        message = "(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you should try below url

request=[NSMutableString stringWithString: @"me/feed"];

Thanks